# Gridview custom adapter button onclick

Tags: android

My gridview custom item is a image button.I want to change image button image when the image button is clicked.You can see below my custom adapter class getView method.But image button image does not change.

```
    ImageButton btn1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myItem, null);


        btn1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    } 


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            btn1.setImageResource(R.id.image1);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> imagesList;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> imagesLis) {
        this.context =context;
        this.imagesList =imagesLis;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imagesList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder      = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myItem, null);
            holder.btn1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.btn1.setImageResource(imagesList.get(position).get("normalImage"));
        holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ImageButton)v).setImageResource(imagesList.get(position).get("selectedImage"));
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageButton btn1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Haresh Chhelana .Well I want to change btn2 image when btn1 is clicked.How should I write?